# PHP MAMP email stopped sending

Tags: php, email, mamp

I'm working on a simple registration email.  I'm using MAMP (free) with PHP.  I was getting emails from my code before.  Now I get nothing.  Here is a test code that doesn't send the email either.

```
<?php
$to = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

What might have changed?  I read that perhaps my ISP blocked sending emails?  How do I find out?

Comment: Hi, are you sure you was using just MAMP or MAMP PRO? Check it out again. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I just moved on to an actual host so I'm not concerned anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be in some way related to the OS X system cron?

I just received this morning half a dozen emails that I tried to send several days ago. Maybe cron ran and sent them? Either that or there's something else further down the pipeline sitting on them...

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal was but just incase someone stumbles on this -> when I moved to godaddy as a host, they batch their emails so it could be up to 15 minutes late.  Godaddy got the axe from me